# Is there way to play HTML5 video in native media player Android?

Tags: android, html, video, media

I have project which have html5 video needed to play in native Android Player similar how it does on iOS.
Is there way to implement it?

I will be grateful for any adivice or solution.Thanks.

Comment: A Simple solution is to use web view.

Comment: Could you show some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you bring some codecs for your file format (.Flv I think)  because android does not have those codes.

For a mp4 file use something like this:

```
try {
        setContentView(R.layout.videodisplay);
        String link="http://s1133.photobucket.com/albums/m590/Anniebabycupcakez/?action=view&amp; current=1376992942447_242.mp4";
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: will I need mp4, webm and flv ?

Comment: Check this page for supported formats: https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html . I edited the response for the mp4 file. Just get the url at put it in the link variable

Comment: Is there way to do this with js

Comment: Do what exactly with ?.. Create an Android view?.. no.. The only things you could do is use a webView in your app or show a link/button which  redirects you to the video url, with the latter opening a browser window to download the video, it will not open the video directly in media player